# Relation name converting from camelCase to snake_case

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

I have a old project on Illuminate Database 4.2 and now i trying to upgrade it to 6.0, but i found some weird stuff: 
i have relation like:

```
public function addressTV()
{
        return $this->hasMany('Billing\db\Models\AddrMapTv', 'StreetID');
}
```

in 4.2 when i use

```
$list = \Billing\db\Models\Street::with(['addressTV'])->get()->toArray();
```

it transforming to:

```
$list['address_tv']
```

Its ok.

But in 6.0 with same code i got:

```
$list['address_t_v'];
```

This creates a lot of problems for me. Is there any way to return the old name conversion?

Answer (score 0):

It might get a bit difficult if you have many relations defined this way, however, the easiest way I see here is to define [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

Your issue here is that `address_tv` key is absent, defining an `accessor` will add that key.

So in your `Street` model:

```
/**
 * Get the street's address_tv.
 *
 * @return object
 */
public function getAddressTvAttribute()
{
    return $this->addressTV();
}
```

did not test it but it should work in theory.